# Is there a type that is the opposite of an enum?

Tags: c#, dictionary, enums, constants

For example, here is a simple enum:

```
enum Something {
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
}
```

But I would like to create the *opposite* of this code, like

```
SomeType Something {
   1 = One,
   2 = Two,
   3 = Threee
}
```

Maybe I could introduce **constants**, like

```
static class Something {
   public const 1 = "One";
   // ...
}
```

but I get compiler errors (CS1031, CS1001, CS0145 and CS1003), because c# can't handle this.
I can do the same with enums to prevent these unnecessary errors, but here I also get CS1001, because c# does not undertand that the numbers are the identifiers.
I can also use strings, but this makes it even more complicated, because c# expects another identifier for them (but doesn't accept one (CS0029))

So, is there anything in c# that can be used to assign some string-like values to numbers as constants or like enums?

Comment: You can use `Dictionary<int, string>`

Comment: Or use it like the first example and cast it simple back: `YourEnum foo = (YourEnum)yourInt;`

Comment: Int key often means *index*, look into arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have numeric value as your variable name, So to solve this issue you can create a Dictionary of key integer and value as string like this `Dictionary<int, string>` and use it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If that's how to use the enum name, you can use `Enum.TryParse<someEnumTyme>(someString, out _someEnumVar).`
But the Dictionary solution of is more elegant in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, for many operations, using an enum variable is the same as using the underlying type.

```cs
enum Something {
   One = 1,
   Two = 2,
   Three = 3
}
Something foo = Something.One; // assign 1 to foo
```

You can use the definition of an enum to create a mapping between values and names;

```cs
   var lookup = ((Something[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Something)))
      .ToDictionary(e => e.ToString(), e => (int)e);
```